# Fork() call - Program never terminated

Tags: c++, fork

I have the following code in which I am using fork. The problem is that my main program does not terminate when I call the function with the fork call inside (although it works fine and does what I want) and I can't find out why. I appreciate any help in advance.

```
while(1)
{
    ClientSocket = accept(m_ServerSocket, 0, 0); //Accept the client;

    if(ClientSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
        cout << "Problem while connecting with client" << endl;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR on fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if(pid==0)
    {
        close(m_ServerSocket);
        int nBytes;

        char inMessage[100]; // The actual buffer

        nBytes = recv(ClientSocket, inMessage, sizeof(inMessage), 0); // Receive at MAX sizeof(inMessage) bytes into inMessage from the client using clientSocket
        if (nBytes == SOCKET_ERROR) 
            cout << "Server: Ah ****... I didn't get it...\n";

        cout << "Received: " << inMessage << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
        close(ClientSocket);//In Windows use closesocket() instead.
        //continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you never exit in the parent?

Comment: You have no termination condition for your parent process. All the code above the final else is for the client process, so all your parent does is close the socket descriptor (which may be bad, btw), then proceed back to the top of your infinite `while(1)` loop.

Comment: You need to add exit() or break in else{} to break from the while(1) loop.

Comment: Yes I see. But if I add break or exit in else{} the problem is that it receives only one message, not all as I want and terminates. Any suggestion for this? Thanks again.

Comment: How do you know when you have gotten the last message?

Comment: What do you mean? I send 4 messages for example and I see them in the console...

Comment: How will the server know if you will send a 5th or if it should terminate after the 4th?

Comment: It should terminate after receiving ALL the messages the client wants to send... Thanks again.

Comment: @SpyrosR and you know when no more clients will be sending messages... how?

Comment: @SpyrosR In that case it is working as you want it to work. It continues to receive messages until you stop it.

Comment: Yes. Any suggestion for stoping it when there is no other client to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like instead of the commented out `//continue;` you want an active `break;`. Otherwise the `while(1)` is never left. After the loop you should `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` or `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!You are right. The problem is that I want the server to keep listening for connections until there is no other client to send a message. Without break in else{} it receives all the messages and in the right order. If I add break it only receives the first message from the first client and then terminates. Any suggestion for this?